# How to simultaneously run pyttsx3 and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a chatbox and want that the user should type command and the computer speaks the code simultaneously but this is not happening ! Which module or function can i use for making it synchronized ?

I have binded a function with  key and when it is hit, the function comes into play. When the computer speaks the tkinter window freezes but i want them both to work at the same time

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[len(voices) - 1].id)

def speak(audio):
    chatbox.update()
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait

def send_btn(event):
    msg = user_input.get('1.0', END)
    msg = str(msg).lower()
    user_input.delete('1.0', END)
    chatbox.insert(END, 'User: ' + msg)
    speak(msg)
```

I expect running the speak function and the tkinter window at the same time and also the tkinter window doesn't freezes!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html) it says that you can put `engine.connect(topic : string, cb : callable)`, try to look in the documentation on running functions simultaneously with the speech.